# Can anyone ID this flower plant by the photo?

Tags: species-identification, botany, plant-anatomy, trees, flowers

Can someone identify this plant? It has big red flowers when it flowers! Not sure if it is native, but it is in my grandmothers garden in Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It seems like it's either a *Paeonia brownii* or *Paeonia californicus*.  According to Wikipedia, these are the only peony trees native to North America, but there aren't any that are native to Canada specifically.  I guess these are the closest you can get.  I added some images to hopefully help you out a bit.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paeonia_brownii

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paeonia_californica

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That'd be a peony tree. I'd say they're a pretty common occurrence!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peony

I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with identifying the individual species, however, if anyone is more knowledgeable here than me.